# In ecplipse RCP application automatically get Run option in menubar Want to remove it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Wsp.png)In my Eclipse RCP application i am getting Run option automatically in menu bar. Without writing any code.So, i want to remove this.

Also getting search menu by default. which is ok for this application. But, my manually created menu item like(File, editor) , these items and search menu item distance not same manner.please help me out this situation to overcome on distance on manu item in eclipse RCP.

Comment: Review the plugins that you are including in the RCP. Leave out the debug and launch plugins if you don't want that.

Comment: IF i delete this from plugins of Run configurations, i will get a error message "MESSAGE Product Automatics.automaticsProduct could not be found."http://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449

Comment: You have probably specified an inconsistent set of plugins. If you don't need anything but the core RCP code the simplest way to get this right is to use a Target Platform containing only the core RCP code - for example the 'Platform Runtime Binary' found [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6.3-201703010400/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just paste this below code in  ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java class.

```
public void postWindowOpen() { 
    // remove unwanted UI contributions that eclipse makes by default
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench ().getWorkbenchWindows();
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; ++i) {
        IWorkbenchPage page = windows[i].getActivePage();
        if (page != null) {

            WorkbenchWindow workbenchWin = (WorkbenchWindow)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            MenuManager menuManager = workbenchWin.getMenuManager();
            IContributionItem[] items = menuManager.getItems();

            for(IContributionItem item : items) {
                if(item.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.run")){
              item.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            // hide 'Search' commands
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use plugin spy feature. `Alt+shift+F1`, `Alt+shift+F2`.
You can use in your development environment first, and you can use plugin spy on your rcp. just add `org.eclipse.pde.runtime` plugin to your rcp.

And you can figure out which plugin contributes menu item on your rcp, and if you think that plugin is not necessary, you can remove that plugin from your rcp.

Answer (score 0):

For removing all defaults options in menu, You need to add this below code in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java class.

```
@Override
public void postWindowOpen() { 
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IContributionItem[] items = ((WorkbenchWindow)workbenchWindow).getMenuBarManager().getItems();
    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
            item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will remind that it is not recommended to use WorkbenchWindow to access the UI, which conflicts with the library org.eclipse.ui.workbench in the Target.

```
@Override
public void postWindowCreate() {
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        IWorkbenchPage page = windows[i].getActivePage();
        if (page != null) {
            IMenuManager menuMgr = getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getMenuManager();
            IContributionItem[] items = menuMgr.getItems();
            
            for (IContributionItem item: items) {
                
                if (item.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.run")) {
                    item.setVisible(false);
                } else if (item.getId().equals("org.eclipse.search.menu")) {
                    item.setVisible(false);
                }
                System.out.println(item);
            }
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet");
        }
        
    }
}
```

I changed it to get the MenuManager from `getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getMenuManager();`

This can solve it.